# Can we get rootview of all the application on screen in order to takea screen shot in android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

Can we get `rootview` of all the `applications` on screen in order to take a `screenshot`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Xamarinify that code:

```
 private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        View rootView = Window.DecorView.RootView;
        rootView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
        Bitmap myBitmap = rootView.DrawingCache;
        SaveBitmap(myBitmap); // ...........
    }

    private void SaveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {

        File dir = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).Path); 
        if (!dir.Exists()) dir.Mkdirs();

        System.IO.Stream fos = new System.IO.FileStream(dir.Path + @"/pic.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        try
        {
            bitmap.Compress(
                Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, fos);
            fos.Flush();
            fos.Close();

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {                
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {                
        }
    }
```

This is far from production ready code but gives you the idea

Comment: It says an object reference is required for the non static field,methods, or property 'Android.Views.Window.DecorView.get'

Comment: Are you doing this from an Activity?

Comment: It's in a service not in an activity

Comment: You will struggle to do it from a Service, need to do it from the Activity in my opinion. You will at least need a reference to the activity

Comment: I want all this to be done in background.for that i am creating a service. let me try with activity once and will then go to service

Comment: Or look into this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779700/screenshot-from-background-service-of-another-application-programmatically Looks like they are executing the system image capture binary and then grabbing the image file

Comment: This did not help me either

Answer (score 0):

Try this for get rootview -

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: No am not able to access getWindow method.

Comment: public void ScreenShot ()
  {
  
   View v = new View (this.ApplicationContext);

   var newView=v.RootView;
   newView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
   if (newView.DrawingCacheEnabled) {
    bmp = Bitmap.CreateBitmap (newView.GetDrawingCache (newView.DrawingCacheEnabled));
   }
   //newView.
  }