# Save as a image which is on android screen

Tags: java, android

I want to save as an image which is on android mobile screen at 10 sec time interval. Which may be home screen or menu screen or any thing. Can anybody tell me how i can achieve this?
I got success for my own application but its not capturing menu screen as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, on most devices it's not possible to get the snapshot of the device outside your application. This, obviously, for security reasons.

This could be achieved accessing the frame buffer at `/dev/graphics/fb0`, but normally you don't have the permissions to read that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a root access to achieve this. Write a [background service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) and execute "/system/bin/screencap" to get the screenshot. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15208441/2626981) to find out how to get screenshot and store in sdcard.

Alternatively you can use [Android Screenshot library](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/) to get screenshots on a non-rooted phones but it requires your phone to be connected to your desktop using ADB.

Comment: I all ready write a background service to take screenshot but not by using su command. Can you tell me this example is also work for non-rooted devices?  I can't use this library because i am writing a network application so there is no option for USB.

Comment: Ok. But if this true then how this application works? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfullnoroot&hl=en

Comment: No, you cannot achieve this on a non-rooted device. You need super user privilege.

Comment: This application used adb integration to take screen shot just like the alternate method that I suggested as it requires you to turn on debugging mode and connect to desktop. However, I am not sure how they manage to capture the screen after you disconnect. But it is definitely a bad idea to enable debugging mode permanently.

Comment: Ok, but how this application works on non rooted device?

Comment: That what I said. ADB integration doesn't require root access