# Get data and interact with running app

Tags: android, opencv, reverse-engineering, bots, xposed-framework

I'm learning about agent-based AI, so, just for fun, I'm going to implement some game bot, using OpenCV for simple android arcade. 
Is it possible to get data from screen and then generate some fake input?
There is no need to make 'screenshot' every frame, as game is some kind of maze.

Also, I have root access and xposed installed, so using of these instruments is acceptable.
Thank you!

Comment: UPD: Found about taking screenshots [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779700/screenshot-from-background-service-of-another-application-programmatically)

Comment: Anyway, question about sending touch events still stands.
I need to touch then grab screenshot, then drag, then grab screenshot, then drag again and so on