# Taking Auto ScreenShot using Services in android

Tags: android, android-service, screenshot

This code is working fine with Activity but not in service.

```
 View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    myBitmap = v1.getDrawingCache();`
```

Comment: Please explain **exactly** what you mean by "but not in service".

Comment: Also add information what exactly you want to do

Comment: Because it does not have the application context in your service..!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screenshot from background service of another application (programmatically)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779700/screenshot-from-background-service-of-another-application-programmatically)