# how to read Memory data from an android app

Tags: android, database

I'd like to get some numerical data from an app, but they are not stored as files like db. I know there are some memory hack apps for changing in game values although I do not know how they work.
I am looking for similar features but I don't need to change anything.

The app I am trying to write just reads some data from a specific app and do some background calculation based on that. If this is not possible, I would need to get information by reading the screen(for example get pixel color), but this seems to be very cumbersome task for getting many data.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Thanks.

EDIT: I'd assume I would need a root permission for this?

Comment: Is it your app that you want to access to read the data?

Comment: @Raptor I wasn't sure how, so I asked here. any relevant idea or where to look for would be very helpful.

Comment: @TedHopp yes, the app I am trying to write will read the data. the data being read is from another third party app

Comment: Unless the third-party app provides some sort of API (e.g., an intent filter) for accessing the data, it's not clear to me that this can be accomplished. Can you provide any more details (what kind of data; whether you have any control of the third-party app; etc.)

Comment: @TedHopp sorry for not being clear. I was hoping for general idea and was going to do some research by myself. The app I am reading data from is a game I have nothing to do with, and I want to keep track of integer number such as score. The purpose of my app is for me to practice coding artificial neural network and hopefully it will play by itself. The main reason why I thought this was possible is because I knew about some apps for game hacking with root permission. I don't need editing but I assumed I would need similar idea.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779700/screenshot-from-background-service-of-another-application-programmatically) has some info on capturing the screen of another app from a service. Due to Android's security protocols, I don't think there's any way to reach into the memory of a third-party app (but I might be wrong about that).

Comment: @TedHopp Right. Thanks for the help Ted!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you would need root permission. Additionally your users must have fully rooted device with e.g. SuperSU or other modern Su app, that can lift most SELinux restrictions. There may also be conflicts with KNOX and other similar systems, but I am not really knowledgeable about those.

You would need to attach your process as debugger to the target application and locate the necessary data by scanning it's memory. This can be done in multiple ways, the best reference implementation to look at can be found in [scanmem](https://github.com/scanmem/scanmem).

The code, performing the actual deed, which requires root rights, — reading/writing target process memory — would reside in a native executable, being run via su. You'd have to write some code to communicate with that executable (probably via it's stdin/stdout or something like that).

You will also have to write additional code to parse the memory layout of target application yourself.

Alternatively, you may prefer to inject a small module in memory of target application and/or have the app itself load a Dex file of you making (especially handy, if your target data is stored in Java memory). This approach have a benefit of minimizing interaction with memory layout of virtual machine, but you still have to initiate loading of initial Dex file. Once Dex file is loaded, you can do the rest in Java code, using good-old reflection API. If you go with this route, a (decently supported!) code for injecting executable snippets in memory of Linux process can be found in [compel library](https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu/tree/master/compel), being developed as part of CRIU project<sup>[[1]](https://lists.openvz.org/pipermail/criu/2015-December/024128.html)</sup>.

Comment: Note, that I am helping you in good faith, but many memory-scanner apps out there have plagiarized open-source code (most notably scanmem) without even giving proper credits to it's authors. Please consider at least sharing memory-scanning related part of your work with other people, if you use scanmem's code. Also note, that above-described method is *very* generic. If you need support for Java apps only, you may be better off using Android Accesibility APIs or Java-remote-debugging APIs to get your way (the former may even be used without root rights!)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helps. This app will be private, just for me. Been learning and coding a bit with neural network, and thought one game would be a good start for practicing against actual game. I just hope obtaining input data is not such a big huddle compared to the actual part of neural network.

Answer (score 1):

Two Android processes cannot share memory and communicate with each other **directly**. So to communicate, objects have to be decomposed into primitives (marshalling) and transfered across process boundaries.

To do this marshalling, one has to write a lot of complicated code, hence Android handles it for us with [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) (Android Interface Definition Language).

From the OP, as no more details can be found, I would recommend you reading/searching with the keyword "AIDL" and you will be redirected to the concrete solutions.

Comment: Thanks for answer. For now, I don't see any relevant part, but I guess that's my fault not being clear what I wanted. I'll keep reading :)